# Create an instance of struct using a function

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I need to create an instance using a function but I am getting an error by using the following code:

```
#lang racket

(struct Mdb(aname bname cname)#:mutable)
(define ainst(Mdb "aval" "bval" "cval"))

(define ff(λ (newname)
            (define newname(Mdb "xval" "xbval" "cbval"))))
```

> > begin (possibly implicit): no expression after a sequence of internal definitions in:   (begin (define newname (Mdx "" "" "")))
> > (define newname (Mdx "" "" ""))

Comment: You can't use a function parameter as a variable name for `define`, it won't work. You'll have to rethink what you're trying to accomplish with `newname`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you *really* want to do? Define a function that creates an instance of the struct? What is the `newname` parameter supposed to do? FYI, this isn't valid syntax, and doesn't make sense:

```
(define ff
  (λ (newname) ; what's the idea of this parameter?
    ; you need to return something after a `define`
    ; or else you'll get that "no expression after
    ; a sequence of internal definitions" error
    (define newname (Mdb "xval" "xbval" "cbval"))))
```

If you want to use a procedure for the heck of it, you can try this:

```
(define ff
  (λ () (Mdb "xval" "xbval" "cbval")))

(define newname (ff))
```

But that's just a contrived way of expressing this:

```
(define newname (Mdb "xval" "xbval" "cbval"))
```

And for the record: you can't use a function parameter as a variable name for `define`, it's not allowed, that's not how a variable definition works in Scheme.